# SwiftUI - How to change the checkmark color of a Picker which is nested in a Form

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change the color of the checkmark in SwiftUI which is used in a Picker nested inside a Form. I tried it with:

> UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black

but that only changed the "< Back" color.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedMode = 0
    private var modes = ["#1", "#2"]


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header:Text("").font(.title)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                ){
                    Picker(selection: $selectedMode, label: Text("Modes")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< modes.count, id: \.self) {
                            Text(self.modes[$0])
                                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is (tested with Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header:Text("").font(.title)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            ){
                Picker(selection: $selectedMode, label: Text("Modes")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< modes.count, id: \.self) {
                        Text(self.modes[$0])
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.accentColor(Color.black)   // << fix !!
}
```

**Note:** `.accentColor` is applied for all `NavigationView` controls, so `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black` is not needed.

Comment: This works, but `accentColor` is deprecated for `tintColor` which does not work.

Comment: Don't care about that until modifier disappears (which will happen not soon) till then I assume they will fix .tint modifier (submit another feedback so this might happen faster).